# is there a way to use @njit AND 2d arrays of type np.object at the same time, to be more efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, numba

is there a way to use @njit AND 2d arrays of type np.object at the same time, to be more efficient?

a and "nan" are two 2d arrays of variable subarray-sizes(each subarray of incrementing (for "a") and descending (for "nan") size). -> since they are in variable shape, they are of type np.object.

merged together they **result in a 2d array where each subarray is of the same** shape.

```
        @nb.jit(parallel=True, forceobj=True)
        def numba_list_comprehension_concatenate(a, b, LEN):
            for i in prange(LEN):
                a[i] = np.concatenate((a[i], b[i])) 
            return a
         
        a = numba_list_comprehension_concatenate(np.asarray(a,dtype=np.object), 
                                    np.asarray(nans,dtype=np.object), np.int64(len(a)))
```

how to make njit usable?

Edit:

```
line 235, in backward_sequentialize
    a2 = numba_list_comprehension_concatenate(np.asarray(a2,dtype=np.object), np.asarray(nans,dtype=np.object), np.int64(len(a2)))#np.asarray([np.concatenate((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,nans)])

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)

  File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
During: typing of argument at D:/.....py (229)




Figures now render in the Plots pane by default. To make them also appear inline in the Console, uncheck "Mute Inline Plotting" under the Plots pane options menu.
```

Comment: So what's the error, if any?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, added it.